# Facing error on preview a VF page Your organization's Salesforce.com pages have moved. Redirecting

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a VF page and embedded the page inside a record layout However it is giving me an error.

Your organization's Salesforce.com pages have moved. Redirecting...

Please let me know what could be the reason.[image]

Comment: Have you switched instances? Do you have any hard coded URLs? Like 'na15.salesforce.com/apex/page'?

Comment: check javascript . might they are causing this issue.